# StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle seems to not work with Entities configured by YML

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, soft-delete

I try to use softdelete in my application, but it doesn't work. When I delete an entity, it's also deleted from the database.

I installed **"stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "1.2.*@dev"** and added it to the Kernel.

My Configuration:

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    orm:
        default:
            ...
            softdeleteable: true

doctrine:
    ...
    orm:
        filters:
            softdeleteable:
                class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
                enabled: true
```

My YML-Definition:

```
...\Entity\Person:
    type: entity
    table: person
    id:
        id:
            ...
    fields:
        salutation:
            type: string
            length: 255
        ...
        deletedAt:
            type: datetime
            nullable: true
```

My Entity:

```
<?php

namespace ...\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * Person
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt")
 */
class Person
{

    ...

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $deletedAt;

    ... 

    /**
     * Set deletedAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $deletedAt
     * @return NaturalPerson
     */
    public function setDeletedAt($deletedAt)
    {
        $this->deletedAt = $deletedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get deletedAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getDeletedAt()
    {
        return $this->deletedAt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your entity is mapped using Yaml, so for Gedmo extensions you will have to use the yaml mapping